# Cannot read properties of undefined error in dependent dropdown list

Tags: javascript, select, typeerror, dropdown

Im trying to make dependent dropdown list. In the first one menu i choose car brand. In 2nd menu I should see only models of selected brand. In a function selectBrand I am trying to set new value of selectedBrand and set models of selected brand to models arrays but in 2nd setAdData I get *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'models')*. How Can I fix that?

```
const [adData, setAdData] = useState({
    selectedBrand: "",
    models: [],
    selectedModel: "",
    productionYear: "",
    countryOfOrigin: "",
    typeOfFuel: "",
    bodyType: "",
    amountOfDoors: "",
    typeOfGearbox: "",
    typeOfDrive: "",
    color: "",
    typeOfColor: "",
    description: "",
    vin: "",
    engineCapacity: "",
    mileage: "",
    horsePower: "",
    price: "",
    creator: "",
    image: "",
});

const selectBrand = (e) => {
    setAdData({...adData, selectedBrand: e.target.value});
    setAdData({...adData, models: data.cars.find(car => car.brand===e.target.value).models})
}

return (
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            
        <Typography variant="h6">Brand</Typography>
        <Select fullWidth value={adData.selectedBrand} onChange={selectBrand.bind(this)
        }>
            {data.cars.map((car, key) => {
                return <MenuItem key={key} value= {car}>{car.brand}</MenuItem>
            })}
        </Select>

        <Typography variant="h6">Model</Typography>
        <Select fullWidth value={adData.selectedModel} onChange={(e) => 
            setAdData({...adData, selectedModel: e.target.value})
        }>
            {
                adData.models.map((model, key) => {
                    return <MenuItem key={key} value={model}>{model}</MenuItem>
                })
            }
        </Select>

        <Button className={classes.buttonSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" type="submit" fullWidth>Dodaj</Button>
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="large" onClick={clear} fullWidth>Anuluj</Button>
        </form>
    </Paper>
);
```

data.json where I have cars and models

```
{
"cars":[
   {
      "brand":"BMW",
      "models":[
         "Seria 1",
         "Seria 2",
         "Seria 3",
         "Seria 4",
         "Seria 5",
         "Seria 6",
         "Seria 7",
         "Seria 8"
      ]
   },
   {
      "brand":"Audi",
      "models":[
         "A1",
         "A2",
         "A3",
         "A4",
         "A5",
         "A6",
         "A7",
         "A8"
      ]
   }
],                                                                              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because in case the user selected car brand does not exist in `data.cars`, and `.find()` returns `undefined`, then you try to read `.models` of `undefined` which gives you an error

One option is you can have a ternary operator to check if find returns an array, then get the models like below (replace `BMW` with `e.target.value` )

```
data.cars.find(car => car.brand === "BMW") ? data.cars.find(car => car.brand === "BMW").models : []
```

---

Concept Working eg

```js
var data = {
  "cars": [{
      "brand": "BMW",
      "models": [
        "Seria 1",
        "Seria 2",
        "Seria 3",
        "Seria 4",
        "Seria 5",
        "Seria 6",
        "Seria 7",
        "Seria 8"
      ]
    },
    {
      "brand": "Audi",
      "models": [
        "A1",
        "A2",
        "A3",
        "A4",
        "A5",
        "A6",
        "A7",
        "A8"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(data.cars.find(car => car.brand === "sd") ? data.cars.find(car => car.brand === "sd").models : []);

console.log(data.cars.find(car => car.brand === "BMW") ? data.cars.find(car => car.brand === "BMW").models : []);
```

Comment: I found a mistake iny my code. When I map through data.cars in Brand Select, I set value of MenuItem as a car instead of car.brand, so when I compared selected brand with data.cars I got that error. Thanks for help!

Comment: ok, if the answer helped can you please upvote or accept? thanks :), its also useful to have fallback checks, just in case